# Parse Facebook Login Crash

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am getting crash in my iOS project when calling `logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`. Here is my complete code.

`let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
})`

The app crashes. Here is my stack trace.

[image]

I am using Parse latest SDK 1.8.1 in my iOS project. Facebook SDK 4.5.1

Anyone facing the same issue?